# Parse string push values in 2D Array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to parse a string of numbers into a two-dimensional square array/matrice the first digit identifies the size of of the matrice for example

Input `45621797533863034`
Here first digit 4 identifies its 4x4 matrice and rest are the values.

so array should be

```
5 6 2 1
7 9 7 5
3 3 8 6
3 0 3 4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC:

```
s = '45621797533863034'
s = np.array(list(s))
s[1:].reshape(int(s[0]), -1)
```

Output:

```
array([['5', '6', '2', '1'],
       ['7', '9', '7', '5'],
       ['3', '3', '8', '6'],
       ['3', '0', '3', '4']], dtype='<U1')
```

If you want the output to be numeric, you can pass in the correct dtype:

```
s = '45621797533863034'
s = np.array(list(s), dtype=np.uint8)
s[1:].reshape(s[0],-1)
```

Output:

```
array([[5, 6, 2, 1],
       [7, 9, 7, 5],
       [3, 3, 8, 6],
       [3, 0, 3, 4]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some fun with views.

```
np.array(s[1:]).view(f'({s[0]},{s[0]})U1')
```

```
array([['5', '6', '2', '1'],
       ['7', '9', '7', '5'],
       ['3', '3', '8', '6'],
       ['3', '0', '3', '4']], dtype='<U1')
```